Determinant of tensor in xAct
I have a Lagrangian that has a term of the form
$$\mathcal{L}\propto\int\,d^5x\sqrt{-\text{det}(g_{\mu\nu}+\partial_\mu\phi\,\partial_\nu\phi+V F_{\mu\nu})},$$
where $V$ is a potential and $F_{\mu\nu}$ is a field strength tensor.
According to the documentation, to use the determinant you have to do so in terms of a given basis, e.g. for a tensor $T_{ab}$ the determinant is given by $\text{Det}[T[-a,-b],\,\text{polar}]$. The exception to this seems to be the metric determinant.
So how do I write such a term before defining the chart?
